# Push notifications don't appear when iOS is on lock screen

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am having a problem letting the OS show the default push notification banner while the app is running but behind the lockscreen.

Test Case:

- Open the app.
- Press on the power button.
- Send a push notification from the server.

Current Behaviour:

- The phone's screen just turns on.
- No notification banner appearing on the screen.

Expected Behaviour:

- OS Notification banner to appear on the screen.

Tested on:
iOS 9 & 10

NB. Push notifications are sent, delivered & displayed otherwise than the above test case..

Comment: could you please specify the code you register with to the remote notifications ?

Comment: How you are very sure that the apns token is valid or the server has delivered push to your system. Use NWPusher https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher to test

Comment: @AbdAl-rhmanTaherBadary I tried both [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:.......] & [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:.....]

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Push notifications are sent, delivered & displayed otherwise than the above test case..